# Are log() statements from dart:developer printed in release?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, logging

Is it safe to use log() statements in the code to log certain things to the console? Will it be visible in release, production mode?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the log() method will be called even though it is in release mode. You can use kReleaseMode from flutter fundation or delete the logs instead.